# Jasmine javascript : how to check response for creating a post some properties as it been created?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am having the following response; how can I verify its been created by having a response contains userid ?

```js
({
  id: '612bd3f42ca01806398da144',
  data: Object({
    createdOn: '2021-08-29T18:37:39.693Z',
    lastUpdatedBy: null,
    userId: '60f469cf784379051298e96d',
    displayName: 'Nadia',
    postText: null,
    postImages: [],
    pluginInstance: Object({
      pluginInstanceId: '1627334094776-047554258642281355',
      pluginInstanceTitle: 'communityFeedPlugin'
    }),
    isPublic: false,
    _buildfire: Object({
      index: Object({
        array1: [Object({
          string1: 'userId_60f469cf784379051298e96d'
        }), Object({
          string1: 'displayName_nadia'
        }), Object({
          string1: 'pluginTitle_communityfeedplugin'
        }), Object({
          string1: 'isPublic_0'
        })]
      })
    })
  }),
  tag: 'posts'
})
```

Comment: What's the context for this question? Are you requesting content from a backend and getting a response in JSON?

Comment: yes I am having json response

Answer (score 0):

If you use express rest api you can use like this.

```
const exists = await posts.findOne({ "data.userid": userid });
if(exists) {
    return res.json({ success: false, message: "User already exists"})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you need to know if the userId property is present/truthy.

Given that the response is stored in a `jsonBody` variable, use an if statement like so:

```js
if (jsonBody.data.userId) {
    ...
}
```

Also, make sure the response is parsed in JSON properly, so that you can navigate it.

If you need to know whether the response exists in the first place or not, you can add another if check:

```js
if (jsonBody) {
    ...
    if (jsonBody.data.userId) {...}
    ...
}
```

Or join both checks in one if statement:

```js
if (jsonBody && jsonBody.data.userId) {...}
```

Anyways, it's good practice to consume backends that comunicate correctly the request status, so that you can write cleaner code avoiding this types of checks and relying on status codes for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

worked in this form :

```
it('Add public post with post image and text', function(done) {
    Posts.addPost({isPublic : true , postImages :'image test',postText : 'post text sample'},(err,resp) => {
        expect(resp.data).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
            postImages: 'image test',
            postText:'post text sample',
            userId: authManager.currentUser._id,
            isPublic: true
          }));
      done();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.